# Java Web Service Oracle

Tags: java, web-services, oracle, netbeans

I have a oracle database with a table tha contains user. I want to create a web service in java to get a user by id. How i do this? I search in the internet but i only get Hello World Tutorials.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use Spring-WS they have a few good tutorials and a few good sample applications that you can modify to meet your needs. You can find out more at :

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/

You have to do a few different things:

1. You should write a simple wsdl to define your web service. This may also require you to write some xml schemas.  You can find some examples here: http://www.w3.org/2001/03/14-annotated-WSDL-examples.html.  Remember wsdls are simply a description of the webservice you intend to write.
2. The next step is actually write the web service. This requires you to generate objects that will marshall/unmarshall requests and responses. The SpringWS documentation gives you a few examples how to do that.
3. Finally  you need to write the database level calls.

Comment: I already develop two web services in Netbeans. One to insert data and another to delete ginving an id. I don't know how to create one to retrieve data given an id.

Answer (score 0):

You really have two problems here:

1. How to query an Oracle database to get records from the user table for a given id.
2. How to expose that method to web clients as a web service.

You don't say whether you want SOAP or REST.

I'd recommend Spring for both.  Its SimpleJdbcTemplate will make task 1 easy; Spring web services will make it easy to write a contract first SOAP service.

Comment: I want to make a SOAP Web Service. I know how to make a select to the database. What i'm learning is to make a webservice where i can retrive something using the id.

Comment: Then try Spring contract first web services.